# Which environment variable specifies current path?

Tags: php, ssh, debian

I'm communicating with a Debian computer via SSH2 PHP extension. Their (not very well) documented [function ssh2_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) states that it's fourth argument is

> an associative array of name/value pairs to set in the target environment.

I want to operate upon different path than `~` to perform `ls` on other directories (as well as making communication more comfortable). But what should I set?

```
ssh2_exec($connection, "ls", NULL, array("???" => "/var/www/"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them. The current path is part of the process state, not the environment. Some shells use the `PWD` environment variable to indicate what the current path is, but it has no special meaning — setting it won't do anything.

If you want to list the contents of a path that isn't the home directory, pass it as an argument to `ls`:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, "ls $path");
```

If you need to run a command that really does care about its working directory, use `cd`:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, "cd $path; command");
```

Comment: By the way, why does SSH not remember current directory for next *exec* calls?

Comment: Because each `ssh2_exec()` call creates a brand-new connection. When the command finishes, it exits.